# Negative look-around

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

the following regexp is wrong - can someone please help to find all :-) that do not have "please ignore me " in front?
I have not previously needed such an regexp. The word boundaries might confuse things.
Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function regexTest(string, assert) {
  document.write('<hr>')
  document.write(string)
  document.write("[")
  document.write(string.match(/\b((?!please ignore me )\:\-\))\b/gi)!=null);
  document.write("]?" + assert);
}

regexTest("1. this is the first string :-)        ",true);
regexTest("2. :-)",true)
regexTest("3. another string:-)here",true);
regexTest("4. Ending a sentence with :-)",true);
regexTest("5. please ignore me :-)",false);
</script>
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups/2973609#2973609

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to match a `:-)` that is not *preceded* by "please ignore me", then you'd need a negative lookbehind `(?<!...)` instead of lookahead `(?!...)`. However, JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind.

So what you could do is to match `(\bplease ignore me\s*)?:-\)` and then, if it matches, check whether the capturing group `$1` is empty.